# Proof that if $n<k$ and $A$ is an $n\times k$ matrix, then $A^{T}A$ is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can I get a proof of the fact that  if $n<k$ and $A$ is an $n\times k$ matrix, then $A^{T}A$ is not invertible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $rank(A) \leq n$ then $A^TA$ is an $k \times k$ matrix and 
$$rank(A^TA) \leq rank(A) \leq n <k \,.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another hint: $A^TT$ and $AA^T$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues.